# Compressing/optimising images with PHP - API vs local?

Tags: php, image, compression, image-compression

I run a lot of websites and at the moment these websites all output large file-sized images. My task is to fix this, and to compress the images on the sites before serving them up to visitors.

I have been researching the best steps to take here, and would appreciate it if anyone could clarify my concerns and/or point me in the right direction.

Here's what I believe my options are:

- Send the image off to an API, download the response, write it to a file.
- Install a compression piece of software so there's no need for an API call.

Option one - sending it off to an API. The benefit here is that the processing is done elsewhere, and will not slow my server down. The downside is that it's slow - so far I've tried out TinyPNG's API and it took over 10 seconds to process a 2mb JPG. What happens if their API goes offline too? Not good.

Option two - processing the image locally. The benefit here is that I can be assured it will work everytime. The downside seems to be that to do this, I need to install compression software onto the server (as opposed to what I was hoping to do, which is just to fire a PHP script). My sites sit on a few different servers and I'm sure some of them will deny installing executables for us to use (especially when they'll use a lot of CPU). I have read that using MozJpeg is a good place to start, but requires installing executables that may be prohibited by most hosts.

My questions in particular:

- Am I correct in assuming that to compress images locally, I need to get my hosting provider to install the software for me? Are there PHP-only options that don't require executables to be installed?
- Generally, would making use of an external compression API make more sense for my use case?
- Finally, is StackOverflow the right place to ask this question? Would I be better off seeking the advice I need elsewhere? If so, where?

Thank you.

Comment: i think SO is the *wrong* place for this kind of question, since it's very broad, very opinion-based and more about software architecture than coding itself. but in general: you *could* write php code that tries to use a local library - if that's not, *fall back* to the web service, and if *that* fails, serve the uncompressed file. also you should check wether all this trouble *is worth* the few bytes you will save by compressing your images

Comment: Hi @FranzGleichmann that sounds like a decent workflow and I will attempt to implement something like that. I did think SO might not be the right place for this quesiton, but couldn't really think of where else it could be asked.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing something similar with an API I am building. Our designer loves using high res, large pixel sized images and we need to then process all of these images to the right size for different devices and placements around our app...

A few solutions I have come up with so far is using something like timthumb (old php image processing "script" may be renamed now) that uses Imagic to resize and scale the images... then I was going to cache them for each size the I output, so if the same image is called at the same res it gets it from the cache rather than processing again

Comment: @joshualawson we used to use TimThumb here before moving over to a slightly friendlier script by a guy called Matthew Ruddy, which does more or less the same thing but uses builtin WordPress functions. TimThumb out-of-the-box does the caching you speak of, so that should save you some headaches. The problem with TimThumb, and ImageMagick though, is that their image optimisation is poor. Using something like TinyPNG, MozJpeg, Jpegoptim etc, can reduce a 2mb file to 350kb. TimThumb would offer far less reduction in file size (2mb -> 1.8mb sort of region).

Comment: You can build your own resizer application easily, check out this repo: https://github.com/sadok-f/flyimg